# Linked list destructor (C++)

Tags: c++

I have circular linked list and i have problem with calling destructor.

This is structure of list:

```
struct LList {

    LList(const string & name) : Next(NULL), Name(name) {
    }
    LList * Next;
    string Name;
};
```

This is my code:

```
~Class (){
    LList * tmp1= First;
    LList * tmp2;
    while(tmp1){
        tmp2=tmp1->Next;           
        delete tmp1;
        tmp1=tmp2;
    }
}
```

I tryed to use valgrind but i am not sure of its result. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Problem is segfault after main function ends. Valgrind says invalid read of size, reporting 100000+ errors.

Comment: no, because you are not telling us what the problem is.

Comment: And the problem is.....?

Comment: What is `Class`? And where is the `main` function where this segfault occurs? Clearly this is not the same code you're having trouble with, but some pared down version that's no longer enough to demonstrate the problem. Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Also, "First" is not defined anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list is circular then the destructor will be an endless loop (or a Russian roulette rather) the way you have coded it.

It should be somewhat like:

```
~Class() {
    // break the circle
    LList cur = First;
    Llist nxt = head->Next;
    if (nxt) cur->Next = 0;
    cur = nxt;

    // walk through the list and delete nodes
    while (cur) {
        nxt = cur->Next;
        delete cur;
        cur = nxt;
    }
}
```

Comment: When it takes second round doesn't tmp2 get equal to NULL so cycle stops ?

Comment: When it takes the second round it iterates random addresses (because memory is deleted and anything else may be using it for different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to put in your destructor is just this:

```
delete Next;
```

What you are currently doing is wrong, because:

1. you dont check that *tmp1* is not null before reading *tmp1->next*
2. if I follow what you are trying to do, calling the destructor on the first element will call *delete* on all the next ones. The thing is, each time you call *delete* on one of them, its destructor will also call *delete* on all the next ones, so you will try deleting objects that don't exist anymore.